# index file Error 500 - server error Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

My shop works perfect, it has nice response, quick loading times, etc....
except for homepage, index or whatever you call it. It always (after loooong loading) finishes with Error 500 - Server error.
Rest of the website works really well.
Did I mess up something?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please read [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: in `config/defines.inc.php` add line `define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);` e.g. after line with php open tag, save file and reload homepage, post error message here or resolve it yourself.

Comment: Are you using any extra module only on these pages?